# Trying to build a single tone guitar tuner. Will my circuit work?

Tags: circuit-design, passive-filter

I am pretty much an amateur in electronics and this is for a university project. I'm designing a single tone guitar tuner. So let me list out my stages,
1) input(i've set it to 196Hz(G note)
2) passive low pass filter to remove noise(im trying to simulate a real life condition)
3) common emitter amplifier to amplify my input
4) a) low pass filter to allow frequencies lower than my desired freq to pass through
   b) bandpass filter to allow my desired frequencies to pass through
   c) high pass filter to allow frequencies higher than my desired  frequency to pass through
Note: I'm only using first order filters due to a lack of components. Would this be an issue since there will be a slower transition from pass band to stop band?
5) comparator stage-(if for example I play a freq lower than what I want(196Hz), input voltage will be allowed through the low pass filter and therefore produce an input voltage(non-inverting input of the comparator) and output a voltage Vp(5V). And since the input is a sine wave, the output will be a pulse. I'm assuming since the frequency is very low, it will be fast enough to light up the LED without seeing the effects of flashing.

I haven't figured out the values to set for each component yet which is why I don't have any graphs to show yet. But I need to know whether my general concept would work or not. Note that there is also a limit to the number of components that I'm allowed to use and I am also only allowed to use a single value for the voltage source(excluding the input). I will post a screenshot of the schematics and also the requirement limits for my project. I forgot to mention that I am also exceeding one capacitor right now and I'm not sure how to remove that.

This is my first time posting over here, so I hope I'm following the right format. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The cutoffs on your filters won't be sharp enough because the frequencies you are interested in are so narrow. There's also a lot more that needs to happen with the amplifier in general (real world stuff to deal with). Instruments also have overtones and not pure tones and that would probably mess with things as well. I don't really know how commercial tuners deal with any of these issues.

Comment: Hint, find out how to wrap Rs and Cs around an opamp to make a higher Q filter. One such would be a Sallen Key, another would be multiple feedback. The nicest and most stable would be a state variable (why else would you be given 3 opamps?). Then you can ditch the under/over frequency channels and claw our component count back.

Comment: But you are building that circuit in a simulator, why not simulate it with various input tones? You will find out that the range that will light up all the LEDs can be surprisingly large, as you have no hysteresis to require a certain amplitude before turning on the LED. Real life guitar tuners may have a microcontroller that is measuring the fundamental frequency somehow, maybe determining signal period with a comparator, or maybe sampling the audio with ADC, to perform Goertzel or FFT algorithms.

Comment: Maybe a bandpass filter running into a mixer to mix with an accurate oscillator, drive an led with the output of the mixer and tune for steady led output or very low frequency blinking (the blink rate of the led will be the tuning error in hz).

Comment: Use your inductors to make a fixed frequency oscillator - Definitely!!      
 I don't think it'll be possible to get a steep enough filter enabled to make your circuit work  (which is not un-clever BTW   ;)  )

Comment: opamps often make poor comparitors, they are better used to make active filters.  Go with Neil's suggestion and learn about state variable filters, everything else should click into place then.  Analog Devices has a decent quick [tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwib8ouxuNfpAhWVpZ4KHdVQCPgQFjAFegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.analog.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ftraining-seminars%2Ftutorials%2FMT-223.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1aQHuS19W-BcQtPOUyr7bW).

Comment: You have a dual polarity power supply but its negative output is not used. The transistor is not biased so its output will have severe distortion. Distortion is high frequencies that will light the "high" LED all the time also when you play the G string too loudly. I agree that your filters are so simple and with such gradual slopes that they are useless.

Comment: How will your design be evaluated? A good guitar tuner has an accuracy of 1 *cent*, where a *cent* is one hundredth of the distance to the next semitone. This is about 0.06%. To be of any use at all, you will need about 1%. Obtaining 1% with a bandpass filter will be extremely difficult.